# Browser can't GET while AJAX sending POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I'm making drag&drop div for picture upload.

1. "on drop" -> loop puts each file in separate array, jQuery creates an image placeholder on the page and calls for "send" function for this 1 file array.
2. "Send" -> AJAX post array to PHP and "on success" calls "show
   upload".
3. "show upload" -> jQuery changes placeholder from "step 1" to an img tag with src to uploaded
   image (thumbnail of picture processed by php).

When I'm trying to upload  pictures (6 or 500), I end up with list of "POST"s (uploads) and list of "GET"s(downloads). The thing is, browser waits for all "POST"s to finish and only then processing "GET"s.

Here is the question:
How to cause GET to work alone/while with post (I obviously want uploaded picture to be displayed as soon as it's on the server) ?
Is it server i have to tweak or code/logic?

*Server: apache.*

P.S.
Will be glad to hear any criticism/suggestions/links.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: Appears, I was running out of maximum number of requests allowed by the browser, So I changed URL to a URI. Now "image" returns with success response. Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

that can appends when you use session in your AJAX action.
PHP blocks other HTTP request in order that only one request a time can access session.

in the AJAX action, try to use `session_write_close` (http://php.net/session_write_close) as soon as you don't need to write in $_SESSION